# Можно ли обойтись без рекурсии в процедуре?

Tags: sql, база-данных, алгоритм, sql-server

У меня есть 2 таблицы:

```
Order_pies: id_Order | needed_ingredient | needed_mass
            2          Капуста             0.3
            3          Капуста             0.3
            2          Мука                0.3
            13         Яйца                0.7
```

И

```
Storage: ingredient | mass
         Капуста      0.3
         Яйца         0.8
         Мука         0.0
```

В `Order_pies` хранятся `id` заказов, которые нужно выполнить, ингредиенты, чтобы их выполнить и сколько этого ингредиента нужно (Я пеку пироги и ингредиенты - это мука, дрожжи и т.д.). Заказов около 50-ти. Каждый заказ можно выполнить только один раз.

Мне нужно создать процедуру и посчитать, какое максимальное количество заказов `Order_pies` можно выполнить, чтобы на складе `Storage` хватило ингредиентов.
В примере выше можно выполнить заказы с `id = 3 и id = 13`, а для заказа с `id = 2` не хватит муки на складе. На выходе хочется получить или таблицу из заказов, которые можно сделать (если несколько вариантов, то какой-нибудь из них), или хотя бы максимальное количество таких заказов.

Эта задача на полный перебор. Я вижу 2 решения: рекурсивная процедура и таблица, в которой перебраны все комбинации заказов. Может, есть решение проще?

Comment: @Mike Нужен один любой вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за интересную задачу, научился работать с XML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получился немного жуткий рекурсивный CTE запрос. Так как для каждого заказа надо сравнивать набор ингредиентов, а MS SQL не позволяет использовать групповые функции в рекурсивной части запроса, пришлось уложить все ингредиенты с количествами в XML. Сначала формируем табличное выражение `C_orders` состоящее из ID заказов и списка необходимых ингредиентов в XML (пришлось так усложнить потому как иначе в рекурсивной части запроса потребовался бы `left join`, а MS SQL и этого не позволяет). После делаем рекурсивное выражение в затравочной части которого всего одна строка с id-заказа 0 и XML содержащей текущее количество ингредиентов на складе. В рекурсивной части берем записи заказов (из `C_orders`) с id большими, чем последний рассмотренный в данной ветви рекурсии. В позапросе разворачиваем XML с текущими остатками и XML с необходимыми ингредиентами опять в таблицы, переклеиваем их, вычитаем ингредиенты и опять сохраняем в виде XML. В условиях склейки в рекурсивной части убеждаемся, что в XML текущих остатков не содержится знак "минус", таким образом мы прерываем ветви рекурсии на которых ингредиентов не хватило. По этой причине в названиях ингредиентов знака `-` быть не должно, либо придется усложнить условие отбора. В итоге запроса получаем список ID включенных заказов через запятую (включая 0, который можно вырезать), количество заказов и XML содержащую остатки ингредиентов после выполнения данных заказов. `TOP 1` из запроса можно убрать и посмотреть все подошедшие варианты.

```
with C_orders(id,mass_xm) as (
   select distinct id_Order,
         (select S.ingredient ing, coalesce(needed_mass,0) mass
            from Storage S left join Order_pies O1
               on S.ingredient=O1.needed_ingredient and O1.id_Order=O.id_Order
             for xml raw) xm
     from Order_pies O
),
CTE(id,ord,cnt,xm) as(
  select 0,cast('0' as varchar(MAX)),0,
       (select ingredient ing, mass mass from Storage S for xml raw) xm
 union all
  select I.id,cast( C.ord+','+cast(I.id as varchar) as varchar(MAX) ),C.cnt+1,
         (
          select CX.value('@ing','varchar(100)') ing,
                 CX.value('@mass','float')-OX.value('@mass','float') mass
            from (select cast(C.xm as xml)) T(x)
           cross apply T.x.nodes('//row') tabM(CX)
            join (select cast(I.mass_xm as xml)) T1(x)
           cross apply T1.x.nodes('//row') tabN(OX)
           on CX.value('@ing','varchar(100)')=OX.value('@ing','varchar(100)')
             for xml raw
         )
    from CTE C, C_orders I
   where I.id>C.id and C.xm not like '%-%'
)
select TOP 1 *
  from CTE
 where xm not like '%-%' and id!=0
 order by cnt desc
```