# Базы данных: Как реализовать систему платежей и графика оплаты

Tags: база-данных

Передо мной стоит задача разработать систему контроля оплаты договоров по установленному графику. Есть два отношения: строчка в графике оплат и платёж, которые ссылаются на договор. FK из договора - это единственное, что их связывает. Подскажите, как можно реализовать связь между ними, чтобы строчки в графике оплат можно было объявлять покрытыми.
Примерные запросы будут такие:

- Вывести строчки, не покрытые платежами (в том числе покрытые не полностью)
- Вывести все строчки и соответствующие им платежи

Сами отношения:

**Payment** ( id, amount, payment_date, contract_number )

**Row** ( id, contract_number, amount, deadline )

P.S. Не хочу создавать связь многие ко многим, так как в таком случае нужен будет триггер, добавляющий каждый поступивший платёж в ассоциативную таблицу.

Подскажите, есть ли типовое решение такой задачи или надо ухищряться?

Comment: Что такое deadline ? Это периодичность или конкретная дата. Т.е. собираетесь ли вы хранить в графике оплат столько строк, сколько платежей ожидается (т.е. скажем по строке на каждый месяц). Или же вам достаточно одной записи с указанием даты начала действия и периодичности (в днях, месяцах или еще в чем) ? И для того и для другого случая выборку отражающую покрытие написать можно. хотя может быть и достаточно сложно, что бы учесть возможность оплаты частями или одной платежкой нескольких периодов.

Comment: И еще решите какая конкретно СУБД у вас используется. конечное решение может от этого зависеть. Красивое решение для одной СУБД в другой может оказаться слишком сложно обслуживать

Comment: @Mike, используется Oracle. График не имеет заданного числа строк. Deadline - это ожидаемая дата платежа, дата, до которой сумма, указанная в строке должна быть погашена (день, месяц, год). Выборкой не получается соотнести платёжи и строки, которые они покрывают

Comment: Т.е. по одному договору может быть много строк "row" с конкретными датами. ok. В БД предполагается фиксировать погашенность строк, т.е. связь между оплатами и требованиями, вычисленную ранее ? Или все рассчитывается всегда "на лету" ?

Comment: А связи в БД всегда диктует сама жизнь. так как один платеж может покрывать как часть одного требования, так и несколько требований, то единственная реализация многие-ко-многим. И интересно было бы увидеть предполагаемый вид вывода всех требований с соответствующими платежами. хотя такой вид называется "Акт сверки", но там связи не видно :)

Comment: @Mike, На данный момент я реализовал рассчитывание "на лету", то есть нет никакой связи между строками и платежами. Но минус в том, что я не могу вычислить, какая строчка какими именно платежами была покрыта.
А если создавать связь многие-ко-многим, то нужно как-то учитывать тот факт, что платёж может быть совершён, но не добавлен в ассоциативную таблицу, и тогда он как бы "не считается".
Вы правы, это акт свёртки. Ассоциативная связь в этом случае - лишнее. Спасибо

Comment: Если подбор должен идти строго в хронологическом порядке (т.е. не надо смотреть "назначение платежа", а предполагать, что самый первый платеж идет на покрытие самого первого требования) то теоретически "на лету" можно и подборку к какому требованию какие платежи относятся сделать. И даже одним запросом. правда запрос будет рекурсивной эмуляцией цикла, так что довольно громоздким и главное, со словом "оптимизация" не совместимым. Т.е. из академического интереса сделать можно и думаю до 10к записей в таблицах даже шустро работать будет. Вопрос в том нужно ли оно

Comment: Вот что то в таком https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660573/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5/660730#660730  роде получится. Правда с xml так может не выйти, надо будет другие пути искать

Answer (score 0):

Можно привязать Payment к Row.
Если я правильно понял, то каждый платеж в идеале должен выполняться по графику.

=> Я бы сделал такую связь:

Contract<-Row<-Payment

Contract<-Payment

По идее, в этом случае не должно быть связи многие ко многим. Можно пойти дальше и отказаться вообще от payment, заменив Ее полем формата xml в таблице row. Не знаю на сколько сложно работать с xml в вашей субд

P.S Row- это глупое название. Назови по другому сущность.

Comment: А что если строка покрывается несколькими платежами? Название и правда дурацкое, debt лучше подойдёт

Comment: Ну так будет 1 ко многим.

Comment: @iluxa1810 А если один платеж сразу за несколько периодов ?

Comment: @Mike ну в таком случае я не вижу способов уйти от многие ко многим. Возможно это и можно сделать, но будет смотреться стремно