# Выборка строк из базы, таким образом чтобы их сумма была не больше заданной

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица mysql
В ней есть поле цена. Существует ли способ выбрать только те ячейки сумма, которых не превышает заданное число и при этом находится максимально близко к нему?
Т.е. есть цены
3 4 5 6
задано число 11.
Выбрать любые строчки, что их сумма была не больше 11.
3+4+5 не подходит, в вот 5+6 подходит.

Sql вообще так умеет?

Comment: Ну во-первых - это задача о рюкзаке. Второе - а вы уверены что это стоит делать на бд, это ну совсем не их задача, конечно можно сделать используя хранимую процедуру и доп таблицу, но лично мне кажется что лучше это делать на нормальном языке программирования. Кстати, задача о рюкзаке np-полная, если есть ограничения на размерности - укажите, иначе за вменяемое время ответ не получите.

Comment: Реляционная алгебра плохо подходит для таких задач.

Comment: Вот похожая задача. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660573/ Но там используется MS SQL который поддерживает рекурсию (без которой подобные задачи не решаются) из коробки. А MySQL ее не поддерживает. Она в MySQL в принципе эмулируется с помощью эмуляции циклов (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673112/#673240) т.е. теоретически даже за один запрос можно сделать. НО 1. на это у меня уйдет пара дней 2. запрос выйдет строк 200 3. мало кто поймет _как_ оно работает и сможет адаптировать это под себя

Comment: Итого: конечно, сделать можно, но оно того не стоит. Лучше возьмите свой алгоритм, написанный на каком то ЯП и перепишите его на язык хранимых процедур MySQL практически один к одному только чуть другими выражениями, возможно будет работать немного быстрее, но только за счет того, что все данные не надо тянуть на клиента.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1 - реализации решения "Knapsack problem" на разных языках...

Comment: Спасибо всем откликнувшимся. Вы убедили меня, что пытаться заставить делать бд, то для чего она не предназначена не лучшая идея

Answer (score 2):

Для этого советую почитать документацию по SQL запросам.
Как вариант, вы можете получить все строки с ценой меньше вашего значения и сделать их обработку уже на другом языке.
Пример запроса:

```
SELECT строка FROM таблица WHERE нужное поле<ваша цена;
```

Comment: У меня сейчас так и реализовано. Просто думал, может это сама бд делать умеет. Все таки задача вроде как не такая уж и редкая