# Помощь в написании sql запроса с использованием dense_rank

Tags: sql, sql-server

Структура:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|unique_host_id |external_property_id|
+---------------+--------------------+
|1              |5                   |
+---------------+--------------------+
|1              |10                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
|9              |10                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Написал такой запрос -

```
SELECT dense_rank() over (order by unique_host_id), unique_host_id, 
external_property_id FROM dbo.host
```

dense_rank() выдает колонку:

```
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы результат был 1, 1, 1. Чтобы значения как-то группировались в одну группу по unique_host_id и external_property_id и ей присваивался идентификатор. Например, если у двух строк равен unique_host_id (пример - 1,5 и 1,10) то им присваивается один и тот же идентификатор (1), но еще если у двух строк одинаковый external_property_id (1,10 и 9,10), то они тоже должны быть в группе и иметь тот же идентификатор. Тогда все три строки будут в одной группе. Как это реализовать?

В данном случае две строки идут в одну группу, потому что у них одинаковое значение в 1 колонке (строки 1,5 и 1,10) к ним присоединяется строка 9,10 потому что у нее совпадает 2 колонка со строкой 1,10. Потому у этих 3 строк должен быть одинаковый ранг (1). Например если есть еще 2 строки в таблице (5,6) и (7,8) , то у них будут ранги 2 и 3 соответственно, потому что значения 1 и 2 колонки не совпадает с другими строками.

Comment: А 4 записи [1 5], [1 10], [2 10], [3 5] то же будут в одной группе ? (первые 2 записи из за 1 и к ним еще добавляется третья так как у нее вторая колонка 10 как у второй записи и в четвертой 5 как у первой записи)

Comment: @Mike да, именно так.

Comment: И если так подумать, то записи [3 20] и [4 20] то же относятся к первой группе, потому что одна запись цепляется к ней через 3, а другая цепляется уже к ней, через 20. А раз так - то тут назревает рекурсивный запрос, который получит некие группы, а потом будет их объединять, если между ними есть хоть какое то пересечение.

Comment: @Mike можете помочь с таким запросом?

Comment: пока не могу придумать. в рекурсиях очень серьезные ограничения на групповые функции. У меня пока вообще нет уверенности, что это реализуемо одним запросом

Comment: @Mike если не реализуемо одним, то как тогда лучше сделать?

Comment: Немного освежил память по ограничениям рекурсии в sql-server ... Для чего вам нужно решение именно одним запросом, не хотите ли сделать это на каком нибудь внешнем языке ? Потому что это может вылиться в какую нибудь такую жуть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660730/194569 ...

Comment: Видимое решение 'в лоб' средствами T-sql: делаем временную таблицу из 3х полей, в которую грузим результат выполнения вашего запроса с dense_rank(). По очереди то по одному полю то по второму берем что то вроде min(dense) over(partition by external_property_id или unique_host_id) меняем в временной таблице поле dense на полученное значение. Продолжаем до тех пор, пока в таблице не понадобилось менять ни одной записи. перенумеровываем  оставшиеся группы по порядку (при необходимости)